# Injection of $F^{\times}$ into its $p$-adic completion

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I've been reading Rubin's book on Euler systems and am having some trouble with a detail from Chapater 3 concerning the cyclotomic unit example. Let $F^{\times}$ be the multiplicative group of a number field $F$. Kummer Theory gives us an isomorphism
\begin{equation}
H^1(F,\mathbb{Z}_p(1)) \cong \varprojlim F^{\times}/(F^{\times})^{p^n}=(F^{\times})^{\hat{}}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{Z}_p(1)=\varprojlim \mu_{p^n}$.
It is claimed that for $F=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)^{\times}\subset H^1(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m),\mathbb{Z}_p(1))$. Now clearly there is a natural map
\begin{equation} 
\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)^{\times}\to (\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)^{\times})^{\hat{}}, \ \ \alpha \mapsto (\alpha \ (\text{mod} \ (\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)^{\times})^{p^n})
\end{equation}
but this map can never be injective for odd $p$ since $-1$ is always in the kernel, and more generally, if $m=p^rm'$, then the kernel is $\pm \langle \zeta_{m'}\rangle$. Is Rubin's assertion that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)^{\times} \subset H^1(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m),\mathbb{Z}_p(1))$ just abuse of notation or am I missing something? At first glance, it does not appear that there will be an issue since the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)^{\times}$ he identifies with an element of the cohomology group are non-torsion, for example $(\zeta_m-1)$.

Comment: I think that’s an abuse of notation, because the map is indeed clearly not injective – but by the (known) abelian case of Leopoldt’s Conjecture, its kernel is finite.